# When to use constructor?

Tags: c#

Im learning c# online, and I just finished an exercise, were I should create a class called "People" and create 5 variables that can make the peoples uniqe:

```
   public string name;
    public int age;
    public double heigth;
    public double weigth;
    public string nationality;
    public int shoeSize;
```

I also created a class called "Bank" and declaired 4 members:

```
    int accountNumber;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string bankName;
```

then, I got the question: "If you think that the bank class is associated with one person (People class) how would you use the class "People" in the class for "Bank" ?

Now I clearly didn´t understand what was being ment.. Any ideas`?

Edit: when do I need the constructor method?

Answer (score 2):

It could be as simple as:

```
public class People // I would call it person though, as People is plural
{
    public int age;
    public double heigth;
    public double weigth;
    public string nationality;
    public int shoeSize;
}

public class Bank // I would call it BankAccount though
{
    int accountNumber;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string bankName;

    // The answer to the question:
    People owner; // <-- Here the bank account has a reference to the People class, 
                  // you provided in the constructor

    // And if you need the constructor
    public Bank(People owner, int accountNumber)// <-- This is the constructor
    {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.owner = owner;
    } // <-- The constructor ends here.
}
```

Comment: Is that inside the class or constructor?

Comment: `public Bank(People owner, int accountNumber)` is the constructor

Comment: The link `People owner;` is the reference inside the Bank class to the people class. And as @Lucas says `public Bank(People owner, int accountNumber)` is the constructor

Answer (score 2):

That's not a constructor, that's trying to teach you that you can have classes you created as properties inside another class you create.

In their example, one person is per bank, so you could have the `People` class as a property called `Person` to signify who the account belongs to. You can do this by adding the following to your `Bank` class:

```
public People person { get; set; }
```

In terms of a constructor, you'd need one if you wanted to set some default properties. Consider this constructor for `Bank`:

```
public Bank()
{
    accountNumber = 1;
    firstName = "Default";
    lastName = "Default";
    bankName = "Default";
    person = new People();
}
```

See that last line that creates `person`? If you removed that, but then tried to do `this.person.name` you'd get a `NullReferenceException`. That's because by default your `person` would have the value of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public class Person
{
    //A property for Name

    //A property for Address 
}
```

In another class a property for collection of `Persons`

```
public List<Person> People { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way I would go:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; } // I would use properties and public properties are 
                                 // starting with a great letter
    public double Heigth { get; set; }
    public double Weigth { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public int ShoeSize { get; set; }
}

public class BankAccount
{
    private Person _person; // private field for the person object
    public int AccountNumber { get; private set; } // public propertie for the account 
                                                   // number with a private setter 
                                                   // because normally you want to read
                                                   // that from the outside but not set
                                                   // from the outside
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _person.FirstName; }
    }
    public string LastName;
    {
        get { return _person.LastName; }
    }
    public string BankName { get; set; }

    public Bank(Person person, int accountNumber)
    {
        AccountNumber = accountNumber;
        _person = person;
    }
}
```

Please allways write down the access parameters from properties, methods etc.